# 2 dimension array, retrieving data

Tags: php, session

```
...
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($results) && $Record_Count < 5) {
      $Record_Count = $Record_Count + 1; 
      $_SESSION['files'][] = $sid . '-' . $data['Id'] . '-slow';
```

would something like this retrieve the files info from $_SESSION['files'][] see below?

```
echo $_SESSION['files'][0];
echo $_SESSION['files'][1];
echo $_SESSION['files'][2];
echo $_SESSION['files'][3];
echo $_SESSION['files'][4];
```

also i'm going to be loop through each item and saving the physical to its correct folder. Within the If statement I'll be adding some extra error checks but does the basic structure look fine, $scrtmp will it go through all one by one or output all arrays?

```
    $scrtmp = $_SESSION['files'][];
    if (file_exists($scrtmp)) {
    @copy("/temp/" . $scrtmp ,"/items/" . date(Y) . "/" . date(m) . "/" . $scrtmp);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operators `&&` and `<` have higher [**precedence**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) with respect to `=` so:

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($results) && $Record_Count < 5) {
```

will be treated as:

```
while ($data = ( mysql_fetch_array($results) && ($Record_Count < 5) ) {
```

assigning `true` or `false` to `$data`.

You fix this by introducing parenthesis as:

```
while ( ($data = mysql_fetch_array($results)) && $Record_Count < 5) {
```

Apart from that I can see few more possible problems:

```
$scrtmp = $_SESSION['files'][];
```

is incorrect. You need to have a 2nd index. Something like:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['files']);$i++) {
    $scrtmp = $_SESSION['files'][$i];
    ....
}
```

Also your `file_exists` function check if the file `$scrtmp` exists in the current working directory (assuming `$scrtmp` has only filename and not pathname). But your `copy` is copying the same file from a directory named `/temp` is that what you want to do?

Comment: thanks, i made the change. is my way of how the 2 dimension array correct for displaying what's inside?